# Program crashes when adding numbers into a string vector

Tags: c++

I have a block of code that calculates some integer and attempts to add it into a `vector<string>`, and it crashes when I run it.

This example crashes when I try to run it:

```
vector<string> numList;
stringstream numstr;
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    numstr << 1 + 200;
    numList[i] = numstr.str();
}
```

Comment: Hi - what is the expected output? what do you mean by "it crashed" - what do you actually observe? is there an error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vector is empty bit you treat it as if it had 100 elements, invoking *undefined behaviour*. Presumably you want to create a vector of size 100:

```
vector<string> numList(100);
```

Alternatively, you can push elements into it:

```
vector<string> numList;
stringstream numstr;
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  numstr << 1 + 200;
  numList.push_back(numstr.str());
}
```